# Abrir archivo para edición a traves de ftp en Java de Android

Tags: java, android, ftp

Cómo se puede abrir un recurso por servicio `ftp` para su edición en Java.

Quiero abrir en modo edición el archivo `.httaccess` mediante `ftp`, es decir que los cambios que se realicen repercuten directamente al servidor web.

Creo que el proceso que necesito seria:

- Abrir conexión FTP
- Descargar el archivo .htaccess
- Abrirlo en modo edición
- Subirlo de nuevo al FTP

O bien si existe algo más directo usando alguna librería etc...

Comment: eso sería un método que funcionaría sin código al lado del servidor. Alternativamente podrías optar por scripts que ejecutas por ssh al lado del servidor.

Comment: Uff, esto se realizaba con apache library,  es una opción!, pero ahora que esta obsoleta para Android no me he actualizado!

Comment: Si he encontrado muchos ejemplos con la apache library, seguiré buscando a ver si descubro una librería de conexión FTP